# Kurt Kinetic Trainer hard to release, should I grease?

Tags: lubricant, trainer

I have a kurt Kinetic trainer. I find that it's sometimes hard to remove the bike from the trainer, as the knobs are really hard to turn. I thought about putting grease on the threads which clamp on the skewer. Is this a good idea or not? Am I likely overtightening the tension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to an email I received from Kurt Kinetic, lubricating the threads is part of normal maintenance. I had to do it because my KK Rock&Roll started making an awful sound. Lubricating the threads fixed this.

Below is the response I received from them.

> We're happy to hear that the trainer provides such great companionship on > those dark and cold evenings!
>
> Below you'll find a basic trainer maintenance video that will address the squeaking noise that does not come from the elastomers.
>
> In addition, please ensure that you're performing regular bike maintenance to eliminate any of other potential squeaking sources.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed. I'll be using chain lube to lube the threaded bits on my Kurt Kinetic trainer.